# Android NDEF intent-filter with data for http scheme and host

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter

I am trying to define an Intent filter that will only trigger when I receive NDEF messages that contain the URI of a particular web site.

I have it defined like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="ta.bcntouch.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But it won't trigger like that. I have also tried:

```
            <data android:scheme="http"android:host="ta.bcntouch.com" />
```

With no luck. Also with just DEFAULT. Removing the  element will cause it to trigger.

Can this be done? The Android documentation only shows examples using MIME type in the  element.....

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the filters I finally used, to capture a number of specific known URL combinations.

The '*' at the start of the host field allows me to use the same filter when testing with test servers that are in a sub-domain, or follow the same format for name.

The second (View) one captures the same URL formats from web-pages, emails, etc...:

```
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/p/.*" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/l/.*" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/a.*" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/t.*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/p/.*" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/l/.*" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/a.*" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="*ta.bcntouch.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="/t/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4):

This format works for me

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.domain.com" android:pathPattern=".*" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My app wasn't triggered if I just added the `android:host` attribute together with the `android:scheme` attribute to my `<data>` tag. But after adding the `android:pathPattern` my app was called by clicking an url matching the _scheme_ and _host_. Unfortunately there is nothing written in the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) that the _pathPattern_ or _path_ attribute is required.

Answer (score -1):

I have done something similar, but I think you cannot use the uri. You need to write a MIME ndef message and assign the custom mime type like x-myapp/mydemo to your activity using the intent filter. you can then read any content, like a URL for example, and trigger a web browser for example.

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for replying. I realize I didn't explain the desired behavior for users.....tell me if you think I can do this with your idea:   I want to push an NDEF with a URL, so that an NFC phone WITHOUT my app can open the url and view content related to the message   OR   if the NFC phone does have my app, then it can capture the NDEF message (url and/or mime) and view it in my app, instead of the web browser.

Comment: I think you have to decide for one of these two unfortunately. If you write a NDEF url type message, there is no way you can link it via mime type to your app only. By the way, if someone else knows about that mime type, he could register that as an intent-filter, too, and again it would not work.